# How to flip a imageView in 45-degree in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have known that

```
imageView.setRotationY(degree)
```

can do a horizontal(0-degree) flip, and

```
imageView.setRotationX(degree)
```

can do a vertical(90-degree) flip.

**What if I want a 45-degree flip?**

How to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to set rotations around both axes....you can use formulae like rotation matrices to calculate what exact degrees you need to set or you can just experiment.

Comment: Thanks, Abhinav! I'll try to use matrices first.

Comment: I try this but failed:  
`Matrix matrix=new Matrix();`  
`imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);`  
`matrix.setRotate(45, imageViewWidth/2, imageViewHeigh/2);`  
`imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`  
The imageView do rotate 45-degree, but after I call  
`imageView.setRotationY(degreeX);`  
The imageView didn't flip in 45-degree.  
It's still flip in horizontal(0-degree).  
I don't want to rotate the imageView itself.  
I want to rotate the matrix of the imageView.